# Remove leading zeros in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have numbers in a table in a database which I want to echo without a the leading zeroes.
When I remove the trim, the numbers are able to echo but with the trim is not echoing, any suggestions?
Here is the code:

```
<?php
     $msg = "SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM Phone) FROM members";
     $msgtxt = $pdo->query($msg);
     $msgtxt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     while($ymsg=$msgtxt->fetch()){
        echo $ymsg['Phone']. ",";
     }
?>
```

But the code is not working!!!

Comment: `var_dump($ymsg)` to see what your result actually contains…!

Comment: One problem is that the PHP code is referencing an array element identified as 'Phone' ...  `$ymsg['Phone']` but the resultset returned by MySQL does *not* contain a column named `Phone`.

Comment: If your phone numbers are zero padded that sounds like a pretty serious bug or case of rampantly dirty data.

Answer (score 4):

Use alias:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM Phone) AS Phone FROM members
```

to get the same column name. Then `echo $ymsg['Phone']. ",";` will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it in PHP, you can use `ltrim` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)).

```
<?php
$phone = '0009398349838';
// Remove leading 0s
$phone = ltrim($phone, '0');
// Print new number
echo $phone;
```

So in your example:

```
<?php
...
while($ymsg=$msgtxt->fetch()){
    echo ltrim($ymsg['Phone'],'0'). ",";
}
...
```